# dynamic DatepickerView and DynamicPicker view for multiple textview

Tags: ios, objective-c, dynamic, datepicker, uipickerview

here I am trying to develop a dynamic `UIPickerView` &
`UIDatePicker` for multiple `UITextFields` in a `UIViewController`. In my `UIViewController` I have five `UITextFields` and by clicking on every `UITextField`, I open `UIPickerView` but my problem is that I want code in which
`UIPickerView` set dynamically in `UIViewController`. Because here I have
also take 5 different date pickerview for that and open it there
particular position by showing & hiding each other as per condition.

For example - I have 5 `UITextFields` in the `UIViewController`. If I select the second `UITextField` then the Y position below three `UITextFields` can be set
automatically rather than set frame of every `UITextField`. Then if I
select the fourth `UITextField` the Y postion of the only fifth `UITextField`
change the three `UITextFields` above fourth `UITextField` would not change. For
more description I see the attach image:

[image]

Comment: are you using auto layout or autoresizing in your UI part

Comment: i am using  autoresizing

Comment: I would suggest you , you should use tableview and create  every section with text field and when the text field is clicked you should reload the section with adding a row in that section with picker view. The all other text filed all move with animation.

Comment: i don't want to use tableview because there are multiple text field and after the textfield portion over there is also scrollview below these so i had also try with table view but it is tough to manage with text field inside picker view in it.. btw ty for your suggetion

Comment: I think when you manually set the y position of textfields and picker view, then you also have to use animations because just hiding and moving the controls will not give smooth effect. With table view and some little complex management that smoothness will be handled for you. :)

Comment: yes you are right but is there any costum delegate to achieve these without using table view because using table view it's very complex to handle frame of different parts of UI view controller

Comment: but if we start to calculate it takes too long code bro, bz we need to write both show and hide

Answer (score 0):

use **scroll view**  or autolayout for this type of problem. or you can use table view in which add the text field and pickerview.

Comment: i don't get you as you suggest to use scrollview because my problem is to set the Y position of pickerview and the rest off the textfield which is below the pickerview. as same like screenshot